# Question about hiring problem

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows

We want to create a new NBA team, we want to keep the tallest candidate. Let's suppose we have n candidates in a random order. So if we have candidate 2 who is taller than candidate 3, so candidate 3 is not hired. Oppositely, if candidate 3 is taller than candidate 2, so candidate 3 is higher. etc.

**What is the probability to hire exactly 2 candidates ?**

For me, I see 3 cases. Let's suppose that each candidate has a rank : ($1$ to $n$, where $n$ is the tallest)

1. The tallest candidate is the first one, so nobody else will be hired
2. The first candidate has a rank $i <= n-1$, so between the first candidate and the $j$'th candidate (where $j$ is the tallest candidate), we should have candidates which size smaller than $n-i$, and then, the tallest candidate ($j$) and finally the rest.

The final answer is $Pr\{T_i\}=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-i}$, where $T_i$ is the probability for hiring twice if your first candidate has rank $i$, but I don't understand how to get it.

For me, first, you should have the probability to have any candidate except the tallest one as first candidate, which is $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Then I'm a little bit stuck (and I don't know whether my reasoning is correct or not) because I would like to compute the probability to have any candidates with lower rank than i and then, the tallest one and finally the rest.

How should I proceed ?

**Bonus : What is the probability to hire exactly m candidates, where $m <= n$**

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly: you have $n$ candidates in some order, with distinct heights. You look at them one by one, and whenever the candidate is the tallest one you've seen so far, then you hire him? Therefore, the first candidate always gets hired?

Comment: As I understand the problem, you randomly select 2 candidates. So the question should be "Find the probability of selecting the 2 tallest candidates randomly". Is this the question you're trying to solve?

Comment: @PedroM. In any cases, you look all candidates (one by one) and yes the first candidate is always hired

Comment: Oh, OK then. Trying to post an answer now.

Comment: What does $T_i$ mean?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, let the random variable $X_i$ be equal to 1 if the $i$th candidate is the largest among the first $i$ candidates. Then $P(X_i=1)=1/i$ and $P(X_i=0)=1-1/i$ for all $i$ .  Since $X_1=1$, the probability that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k=2$ is equal to the probability that exactly one of the $X_2,\ldots,X_n$ is equal to 1 and the others are zero. This probability is easily calculated, using  the (nontrivial) fact that the $X_i$  are independent. For example,for $n=3$, the probability has the value 1/3+1/6=1/2.  In general, the probability mass function of $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ can be calculated from its generating function, which  is given by the product of the terms $1-1/i+z/i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Using computer algebra, you can expand  this product into a polynomial of degree $n$.   The coefficient of $z^m$ in this polynomial gives you the probability that exactly $m$ of the $n$ candidates will be chosen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm lost when you give the example for n= 3. If I'm right, we know that $Pr(X_1) = 1$ and so $\sum_{k=2}^{n=3}X_k = 1$. So, how can you obtain $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: The probability is $P(X_2=1,X_3=0)+P(X_2=0, X_3=1)=P(X_2=1)P(X_3=0)+P(X_2=0)P(X_3=1), by the independence of $X_2$ and $X_3$.

Comment: Let's assume that I cannot use computer algebra, how should I find $\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-i}$ ?