# Probability that exactly k out of n candidates are hired in the Hiring Problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Here's the description of the hiring problem.

Hiring Problem

• Need an office assistant

• Employment Agency sends one candidate every day

• Interview that person, either hire that person (and fire the old
one) or keep the old person

• Always want the best person – always hire if an interviewee is
better than the current person.

You can read more about the problem [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/cs673/lecture/lecture2.printable.pdf) to have a better understanding of the problem.

This question is similar to the one asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546384/secretary-problem-the-probability-of-hiring-exactly-k-times). I am not sure if the answer given for that question is a correct one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secretary Problem: The probability of hiring exactly $k$ times](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3546384/secretary-problem-the-probability-of-hiring-exactly-k-times)

Comment: @RadialArmSaw It should be noted that the accepted answer to that question is incorrect, although a correct solution has just been posted.  I don't know what to do with duplicates in such a case.  Also, despite the title, it really only addresses the case when $k=2$.

Comment: @saulspatz I did not post that comment.  I reported the post and gave the duplicate.  I guess it posted automatically.  That’s weird.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Yes, it always posts then when you report a duplicate.  It used to say something else.  They just changed it recently.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for answering. This answered my question.

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so that the question no longer shows as unsolved.

Comment: Sorry. I have never asked question here before. I did not that i would have to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(n,k)$ be the probability of exactly $k$ hires among $n$ candidates.  I'm not sure that there's a compact algebraic formula for $P(n,k)$, but there's a simple recursive one.  We have the boundary conditions, $$
\begin{align}
P(n,k)=0,\ k>n\\
P(n,1)=\frac1n\\
P(n,n)=\frac1{n!}
\end{align}
$$
Call the least favorable candidate $1$, the second-worst $2$, and so on.  If candidate $m$ comes on day $1$ the $m-1$ candidates worse than $m$ may be ignored and we will hire $k$ candidates if and only if we hire exactly $k-1$ from the remaining $n-m$.  Since the probability that candidate $m$ is the first to show up is $\frac1n$, we have $$P(n,k)=\frac1n\sum_{m=1}^kP(n-m,k-1),\ 1<k\leq n$$

**P.S**

As you suspected the accepted answer for the cited question is wrong, but a correct one has been posted recently.

Comment: $|s(n,k)|/(n!)$, where $s(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the first kind. In fact, [OEIS A008275](https://oeis.org/A008275) notes "The unsigned numbers are also the number of permutations of 1..n with k left to right maxima."

Comment: Why is there a $\frac{1}{n}$ in front of the summation?

Comment: @MatthewEngelstein Whoops, I left out a few words.  The probability that the first candidate to show up is candidate $m$ is $\frac1n$.